# same osmotic pressure of different solution

Tags: cell-membrane, osmosis

For example, There is a sugar solution with concentration $A_{1}$, how to determine the concentration of a NaCl solution which produce same osmotic pressure as the previous sugar solution toward animal's cell?

Is this ratio various between different kind of cells?

NOTE: the unit of concentration is not important between mass/vol or mol/vol. Because when one is known, the other is easy to compute.

Comment: Is `A1` known? If yes, have you taken a look at [this video?](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/health-and-medicine/lab-values/v/calculate-your-own-osmolarity)

Comment: @SPr, Yes, it is known.

Comment: This is a simple chemistry question. The answer is 0.5A₁ but I won't explain why. Read about colligative properties. I am VTCing this as a homework/General Chemistry question.